# Working of @CacheLookUp of PageFactory in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I am not very clear with the concept of @CacheLookUp in PageFactory. I used it in my framework for every element but many times it leads to Stale Exception in selenium. On removing the @Cache annotation, it starts working fine.

Please explain the internal working mechanism of @CacheLookUp so that I starting using it nicely, where ever it is required.

Comment: This annotation will cache the element or element list, so repeated access will not lead to an actual findElement(s)method call. If the element you are referring to undergoes any DOM changes then the cachelookup will throw stale element exception. In those cases do not use this annotation. Look up the source code for  org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? What does it say? What are you confused about? I don't see much research effort here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Extra information which might be useful***
When PageFactory initializes a WebElement which is decorated with @FindBy or @FindAll annotation, it creates a Java proxy object. This way PageFactory is able to delay load elements and is also able to avoid the FindElementBy call on the Browser's WebDriver during PageObject initialization.

To the point, this means that Proxy object has to resolve the actual WebElement to make all the necessary calls on the WebElement. There are logically two ways to do it
1. Either find the element every time you need it (Which is time consuming because of a FindElement REST call to WebDriver)
2. Or to cache the element from the very first FindElement call to WebDriver and return it in subsequent calls. (This is not a good idea for elements which are dynamic, that is refresh multiple times during there life time in DOM, because referring to a older cached version will result in State Element exception.

To cater to these two ways to find element, Smart people from Selenium Dev team created the @CacheLookUp annotation. If you use this annotation you can instruct Selenium to not make a FindElement call to Browser's WebDriver every time.

I recently wrote an article around the performance benefit of @CacheLookup. You can read it here on [ToolsQA - @CacheLookup](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/cachelookup-in-pageobjectmodel/)

It will also suggest when to use @CacheLookup and when not to use it.

If you want to debug the code to understand the working then you have to look at these two key interfaces.
1. org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.ElementLocatorFactory : This helps PageFactory get ElementLocator.
2. Second interface is  org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.ElementLocator. Concrete implementation is DefaultElementLocator.

To start debugging you can step inside PageFactory.initElement and that will lead you through these two interfaces to the implementation of [DefaultElementLocator](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/DefaultElementLocator.java). This is where you can find the caching logic.